# 240V Mains - Current draw and when to use Solder vs Welding

Tags: current, mains, high-current

No specific application, just for interest - I opened up a multiplug/multiboard and noticed that all the contacts for welded (i.e. no solder).  I was just wondering if this had anything to do with current draw, and (if so) what's the upper 'safe limit' for solder - and when should you be thinking about using welds instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not going to be some specific number here because it depends a lot on other aspects of the design besides just the solder joint.

The upper safe limit for a solder joint really depends on several factors.

- The geometry of the joint (length and cross section), which determines dissipated wattage at a specific current level.  Making the joint wider or shorter will reduce wattage and allow you to carry more current.
- The melting point of the solder.
- What paths the heat has to get out of the joint.

Typically solder joints have resistances in the range of micro-ohms and melting points of hundreds of degrees C.

For example,  [Lead Free Solder Sn96 (SAC 305)](https://www.alliedelec.com/m/d/8d9ef1f686bf70839a288bf4fd8e669e.pdf) has a resistivity of 13 micro-ohm-cm.

A joint made from this solder with a 100 mils x 100 mils cross section and thickness of 20 mils would have a resistance of only 10 micro ohms.

You would have to run 100A through it to generate even 0.1W of heat.

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative answer.   That's the kind of technical background / musings that I was after :)

Answer (score 4):

It's more likely to do with manufacturing cost, multiplugs/boards are built down to a price. Once you're into manufacturing volumes, spot-welding is fast and can be automated.